# Is there a better way to make this "corner ribbon/label" remain proportional/responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have recently been wanting to make these cool sort of ribbons/labels that sit on a little pricing-plan table kind of thing for my website.

[Here](https://gyazo.com/74364f689983b99c4d11bc5089ae0c93?token=1f2bf5a3b10d32e9a652e6bb27a9941f) is what I want it to look like, nothing simple.

I was able to achieve this:

```css
html{
 font-size:16px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
}

body{
 height:100vh;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.box{
 position:relative;
 width:300px;
 height:400px;
 background-color:orange;
 
 overflow:hidden;
}

.label-referencepoint{
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 background-color:black;
 
 transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.label{
 position:absolute;
 transform:translateX(-50%);
 padding:1em 3em 0 3em;
 background-color:deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="label-referencepoint">
  <div class="label">New!</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

It works quite well and you can change the font-size from the HTML class to see it stay proportional and responsive.

**Here is my logic behind it:**

I have a reference point at the top-right corner of my container, it has a width and height of 0. It is also rotated 45 degrees. Inside it, I have the actual ribbon/label with a top padding of 1em and side padding of 3em to stretch out and fill its width. The container obviously has to be overflow:hidden otherwise the ribbon's background would just stick out.

Anyways, I was wondering if there is a better way to do it, maybe without having to use a reference point?

Comment: Can you post the HTML in your question as well?

Comment: Yeah, I just did.

Comment: Maybe you can get some inspiration from these guys: http://www.cssportal.com/css-ribbon-generator/